# URL - Not able to export sheet table data in csv file , It always return html content file or junk characters instead of table data

Tags: java, url, inputstream, httpurlconnection, tableau-api

I am able to hit the tableau server url from browser and download the csv file successfully (Report).But when try to achieve same from java program it does not work. It always return html content instead of table data in csv.

I prepared the same request from developer tool but still it's not working.

```
URL- http://170.10.11.180/#/site/vodafoneid/views/My-Store-WB-sheet2-test4/Sheet1.csv    
Network --> Headers
    General
      Request URL:http://170.10.11.180/t/vodafoneid/views/My-Store-WB-sheet2-
      test4/Sheet1.csv
      Request Method:GET
      Status Code:200 OK
      Remote Address:170.10.11.180:80
      Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

    Response Headers 
      HTTP/1.1 200 OK
      Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 03:16:33 GMT
      Server: Tableau
      X-Tsi-Request-Id: WQFikKweEMEAABAIiXwAAAE@
      Pragma: 
      Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
      Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
      Content-Disposition: inline; filename*=UTF-8''Sheet1.csv
      Content-Type: text/csv
      Content-Length: 696
      P3P: CP="NON"
      X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
      Keep-Alive: timeout=8, max=97
      Connection: Keep-Alive

    Request Headers
     GET /t/vodafoneid/views/My-Store-WB-sheet2-test4/Sheet1.csv HTTP/1.1
     Host: 170.10.11.180
     Connection: keep-alive
     Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
     User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
     Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
     Accept: 
     text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
     Referer: http://170.10.11.180/
     Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
     Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
     Cookie: workgroup_session_id=e63C17QVsYYb96QjgucEErCN9FfhBOj8; XSRF-
     TOKEN=UnsKX3TNkn38alNR5QSVjJYGsF4q6v9X; tableau_locale=en
```

Sample Code :

```
String exportWorksheetURL = "http://170.10.11.180/trusted/fNFjAo3gT4m7BmnY-4pklA==:YOIY6VzskdubgRz_OmFa2RUB/t/vodafoneid/views/My-Store-WB-sheet2-test4/Sheet1.csv";

URL url = new URL(exportWorksheetURL);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

//Set request headers  
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/csv");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

// Get Input stream object to write csv file.
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

if ( in != null) {
    File downloadfile = new File("c:/sheet1.csv");
    Files.copy( in , downloadfile.toPath(),
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Can any one please suggest, what is wrong here ?

Comment: In debug I noticed that connection object contains response code as 200 and  requesturl as : /en/embeddedAuth.html?path=%2Ft%2Fvodafoneid%2Fviews%2FMy-Store-WB-sheet2-test4%2FSheet1.csv%3F%3Aembed%3Dy&siteUrlName=vodafoneid&siteLuid=&authSettings=DEFAULT  and sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection:http://170.10.11.180/en/embeddedAuth.html?path=%2Ft%2Fvodafoneid%2Fviews%2FMy-Store-WB-sheet2-test4%2FSheet1.csv%3F%3Aembed%3Dy&siteUrlName=vodafoneid&siteLuid=&authSettings=DEFAULT

Comment: In Fiddler tool i can see 2 request : 1. http://170.10.11.180/trusted/BJXdLJzrRtS4sZjo6rPihg==:b_lQSTaJj7aluxD4Hq1ZAZmR/t/vodafoneid/views/My-Store-WB-sheet2-test4/Sheet1.csv        2.  http://170.10.11.180/t/vodafoneid/views/My-Store-WB-sheet2-test4/Sheet1.csv?:embed=y

Comment: As per my analysis via Fiddler tool, At browser level internally 2 request gets trigger , Where in first request response received as html with HTTP/1.1 302 Found , then tableau internally call 2nd request (HTTP/1.1 200 OK) and return the actual data in csv.

Comment: First Request - HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 09:55:43 GMT Server: Tableau X-Tsi-Request-Id: WQHAH6weEMEAABAIjnwAAAFE Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store Location: ttp://170.10.11.180/t/vodafoneid/views/My-Store-WB-sheet2-test4/Sheet1.csv?:embed=y Content-Length: 0  Path=/
P3P: CP="NON"
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
Keep-Alive: timeout=8, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/csv

Comment: Second Request - HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 09:55:43 GMT Server: Tableau X-Tsi-Request-Id: QHAH6weEMEAABAIjn0AAAFEPragma: Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMTCache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Disposition: inline; filename*=UTF-8''Sheet1.csv
Content-Type: text/csv Content-Length: 696 P3P: CP="NON"
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge Keep-Alive: timeout=8, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive  Customer ID,Customer Name,Measure Names,Measure Values
DP-13000,Darren Powers,Salary,"1,000"
DP-13000,Darren Powers,Sales,20